# Search Query for Google Analytics

Tags: search, google-analytics

I am a newbie. I am setting up my google analytics account. It is asking for search query for my website. can anyone help to find search query for http://dashcamsonly.com.au , or guide me how to find it ?

Answer (score 2):

Your search query is q.

I got his by doing a search on your website for blah - http://dashcamsonly.com.au/catalogsearch/result/?q=blah

*Note the ?q=. Where q is your search query parameter.

See Google's documentation: [Identifying Search Query Parameters for your Site](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012266) and [Set up and configure Site Search](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en&ref_topic=1031951)